# Can you increase the console popup menu with task submenu entries?

Tags: windows-10, console, conemu, tasks, cmder

I have to work with a lot of vms and I'm using task submenu to group vms in console popup menu. The issue is that now I have more vms than entries in the task sub-menu to create putty sessions.

I tried both Cmder and ConEmu and the maximum number of entries is 30 from [0-9] and [A-T].

Can you increase the task submenu entries in ConEmu or Cmder?

Is there another way that I can add more than 30 vm entries to choose from for one category?

Comment: What's the problem to create another category/folder?

Comment: There is no problem in the end. For my workflow I would liked it more to the larger category folders.